# Why is the Bernoulli Number $B_1$ sometimes $+ \frac{1}{2} $?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

By using the recursive formula,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{i} B_i = n+1 
\end{equation}

we find $B_1$ to be $\frac{1}{2}$ and not $- \frac{1}{2}$. Why is this?

Comment: Just different conventions in the definition of $B_n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Different_viewpoints_and_conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Lundmark's comment that there are different conventions in the definition of $B_n$ might bring up the question "why can there be more than one convention"?

This is the true reason (answer) to your question.

Simply put, $B_2$ through $B_n$ can be constructed from $B_2$.  Therefore $B_0$ and $B_1$ can be defined however we need them to be to fit our needs, including the fact that we can simply omit both of them.

If you wish to know how I learned this on my own "from scratch", feel free to read the content (and view the images in the "spoiler tags") I have written in the spoiler of [this post](https://www.speedsolving.com/forum/showthread.php?35625-Mathematics-Thread&p=760917&viewfull=1#post760917) up until the line "I then wrote the following recursion formula from the triangle:".  (Specifically, see [this image](http://i.minus.com/iThNlCXLozVM0.gif).  You will see that I assigned $B_1 = -1/2$ in the image, but I could have just assigned it to be "x" if I wanted to, and that wouldn't affect the values of $B_2$ through $B_n$.)

Lastly, for a video explanation and proof of my "adjusted Pascal's triangle" for the integer power sum formulas, you may also watch my [YouTube video presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhoOH_byPSQ%20pla).